# R.id.myEditText error // todolist attempt

Tags: android, r.java-file

Hey guys, 
i bought an android dev book from WROX (Android 2 application development) and on chapter 2 they have an average task list project that i can't seem to get working.

I copied the exact line of code and tried tweaking them to get it to work but the following line remains an error no matter what i do.

```
final EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
```

the error is the `R.id.myEditText`, i've added it to the R.java file but no luck it doesn't want to work.

the java file for it is the following.

---

```
package com.paad.todolist;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView; 

public class ToDoList extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    final EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

    final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);

    myListView.setAdapter(aa);

    myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
                    todoItems.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
                    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    myEditText.setText("");
                    return true;
                }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

}
```

---

### the XML file is the follwing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/myListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

Any ideas?

Comment: The R class is created automatically. You shouldn't add anything to it.. Try to delete it and rebuild the project (clean), maybe t will help you.

Answer (score 4):

You dont update your R.java file directly, this is generated automatically when your project is built.  The issue is that you have not added the EditText to your layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
```

Comment: I added this to the xml file and the error remains the same, any ideas?

Comment: @Chaoticandroid have you performed a clean and build?

Answer (score 1):

If you change

```
android:id="@+id/myTextView"
```

to

```
android:id="@+id/myEditText"
```

it should work.

What's happening under the hood? When you define an element with a specific id in XML file, Android tools (Eclipse probably in your case) will regenerate `R.java` file.

`R.java` should never be edited by hand, think of it as a source file that represents your XML elements in a type safe way which you can access in Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Change your xml file as below and then try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:orientation="vertical"     android:layout_width="fill_parent"     android:layout_height="fill_parent"     > <EditText     android:id="@+id/myEditText"     android:layout_width="fill_parent"      android:layout_height="wrap_content"      android:text="@string/hello"     /> <ListView     android:id="@+id/myListView"     android:layout_width="fill_parent"     android:layout_height="wrap_content"      /> </LinearLayout>
```